# Is Quotes necessary in yaml? I was creating a python script to edit docker compose YAML values but the quotes are not preserved

Tags: python, list, yaml, pyyaml

I am not supposed to use ruamel , but need to preserve quotes. Is the quotes necessary in first place?
eg shm_size: '1gb' vs shm_size: 1gb will it make any difference?

i have used the yaml package of python for loading and dumping the yaml.

Comment: One of the stranger things of YAML is that quotation marks can matter sometimes unexpectedly. For example version numbers can be interpreted as floats which can make a `3.1` out of `3.10`.

Comment: Something i have noted is that the version number have the quotes maintained , how does PYaml do this.                                                                                               
 version: '2.3'
services:
  log:
    image: goharbor/harbor-log:v2.5.5
    container_name: harbor-log
   But nowhere else the quotes are preserved.

Answer (score 0):

While loading PyYAML converts anything that is quoted (in YAML) to a string, but it doesn't preserve the information on the original quotes used. If you then dump that string, PyYAML checks if that string needs quoting or not. It does so by "temporarily" dumping just the individual string as a scalar without quotes and then loading it back. If it doesn't load back as a string, it will quote the scalar in the output.

So if you load `"abc"` and then dump it you will get `abc`. But if you load `"6.0"` or `"2023-02-16"` you will get `"6.0"` resp `"2023-02-16"`, because not quoting would result in a float resp. date. If you have scalar like `"2.5.5"` in your YAML, this can never be confused with a float because of the double dot, so it doesn't need quoting when dumped.

Please note that PyYAML will also put quotes around `Yes`, `No`, `On`, and `Off` although those alternatives for `True` and `False` were dropped from the YAML spec back in 2009. I.e. PyYAML still only supports a subset of YAML 1.1.

So quotes are sometimes necessary in YAML, in cases where not using them would result in type conversion during loading, and this should be taken into account while dumping. Conversely, if they are **not** necessary, then using them or not makes no difference for the loaded data.

If you are concerned to keep the quotes, e.g because you need to check in the YAML into a revision control system and don't want programmatic updates to create spurious changes, I suggest you look at `ruamel.yaml` (disclaimer: I am the other of that package, derived from PyYAML back in 2014). It supports preserving quotes even if not necessary, in addition to preserving comments, alias/anchor names, precision and formatting in floats/ints, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Anthon, now i think PyYAML is fine for editing docker-compose.yml, cause it preserves the quotes in needed scenario. But have you ever experienced an occassion where using PyYAML has backfired you becuase of missing quotes... Given ruamel is the last option for me..I would be forced to use sed commands instead of ruamel (by my team, or need to give a detailed reason for a new package)

Comment: Docker compose switch to defaulting to `docker-compose.yaml` several years ago and now `compose.yaml`. PyYAML will just lose comments, when you edit the `compose.yaml` file programmatically. Humans looking at the file (or even updating stuff in it that outside of the automated stuff) will find such comments useful. So IMO you then better use `sed` than PyYAML. The first ruamel.yaml version was released in 2015, so it is not a newcomer. Compare that with PyYAML supporting only partially a 14 year outdated spec...